# Autosize font in multiline textblock

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I try to set maximum possible font size in a text block. I found this solution:

```
<Viewbox
       StretchDirection="Both"
       Stretch="Uniform">
       <TextBlock
            TextWrapping="Wrap"
            Text="{Binding LongText}"/>
</ViewBox>
```

This works perfectly when the text is short in one line, but the multiline text is written in one line, and it's very small (wrapping don't work). How I can make it bigger?

Comment: Set the TextBlock's Width.

Comment: width as parent width? I set Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ActualWidth}" and still doesn't work

Comment: No, some fixed width - that results in the desired wrapping.

Comment: but my window can be resized and text can be different. How I can chose width?

Comment: Choose the width so that an appropriate number of lines is shown, depending on the length of the text, and the default font size. The scaling is then done by the Viewbox. There is no automatism that implements your requirement.